# Trouble with if statement in java

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Hi everybody I'm a noob to java so not sure about its querks, but this works in C# so ?? 
having some trouble getting the same results with this bit of code :

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){

        ar1 = array[i][0];
        ar2 = array[i][1];
        ar3 = array[i][2];
        ar4 = array[i][3];
        ar5 = array[i][4];
        ar6 = array[i][5];

        if (ar1 == rs1 || ar1 == rs2 || ar1 == rs3 || ar1 == rs4 || ar1 == rs5 || ar1 == rs6)
            M++;

        if (ar2 == rs1 || ar2 == rs2 || ar2 == rs3 || ar2 == rs4 || ar2 == rs5 || ar2 == rs6)
            M++;

        if (ar3 == rs1 || ar3 == rs2 || ar3 == rs3 || ar3 == rs4 || ar3 == rs5 || ar3 == rs6)
            M++;

        if (ar4 == rs1 || ar4 == rs2 || ar4 == rs3 || ar4 == rs4 || ar4 == rs5 || ar4 == rs6)
            M++;

        if (ar5 == rs1 || ar5 == rs2 || ar5 == rs3 || ar5 == rs4 || ar5 == rs5 || ar5 == rs6)
            M++;

        if (ar6 == rs1 || ar6 == rs2 || ar6 == rs3 || ar6 == rs4 || ar6 == rs5 || ar6 == rs6)
            M++;


        if (M == 3)
            w3++;

        if (M == 4)
            w4++;

        if (M == 5)
            w5++;               

        if (M == 6)
            w6++;

    }
    lbl3.setText(String.valueOf(w3));
    lbl4.setText(String.valueOf(w4));
    lbl5.setText(String.valueOf(w5));
    lbl6.setText(String.valueOf(w6));
```

In the for loop it:

1. sets ar(N) to part of the array
2. checks against rs(N) then increases M if true
3. checks M to see if its 3,4,5,6 then increases w(N) if true
4. at the end displays to a label all the totals of w(N)
   e.g. lbl3, 10
       lbl4, 22
       lbl5, 12
       lbl6, 6

But all I get is one label giving a total 1 or all giving 1!!
Have tried enclosing in {} and using (else if),
array is full, so I'm stumped!!!

Comment: My eyes.........

Comment: what is rs1, rs2..., rs6?

Comment: WIthout knowing more about the values and types of the array and the rs variables, it's hard to help. Perhaps 1 is the correct answer for all cases?

Comment: Hi thank for replies there Integers, @ Robert Griesmeyer thanks that cut the code a bit but still only get 1 in 1 label. @ kufudo no have check in a listview and there should be 32 split between all labels, thanks so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the objects are primitive types, use .equals instead of ==

Also, assuming your types are strings, I'd put the rs's into a Set and then do a contains.

```
Set<String> ares = new HashSet<String>();
ares.add(r1);
...
ares.add(rN);

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) {
       if (ares.contains(array[i][j])
           M++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi have tried but still just get 1 in a label instead of 32 split between all labels, thanks for your input Scott

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to assign so many variables in the first place.  If you simplify things it could make debugging easier.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
        value = array[i][j];
        if(value == rs1 through 6){//check to see if value equals all of the rs1, rs2, etc... variables   
            M++;    
        }
    }
 # assign W variables...
}
```

If you still are not getting the variables that you expect you could put intermittent print statements inside of the loops to see the values are at different iterations of the loop.  But, I would advise that you use a debugging program that sets breakpoints so that you can expect variables during execution. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks that cut the code a bit but still only get 1 in 1 label  instead of 32 split between all labels, thanks for your input Robert